# Firebase: How to access current users posts

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a view controller with a tableview that shows all posts by all users, however I am looking to have another view controller with another tableview that displays only the current users posts. This tableview will allow the user to control/delete their posts.

I have the tableview with all the posts however I am unable to get only the current users posts.

How am I able to do this?

Comment: First, please include Code and Firebase Structures as text please, no images. Second, you don't have any way to know which user posted the post in your question. Lastly, if you stored the uid of the user who posted the post as a child node of the post, then you could simply query for all posts posted by that user.

Comment: @Jay to store it as `uid: ...userId...` or as `ref: /Users/...userId...` ?

Comment: @MikeMaus I am not sure the difference between those two options is clear - I think my comment is a good opton - store the users uid as a child of the post and then that user can easily retrieve their posts via a query on the posts node. I would suggest posting a question including a description of what you're attempting to do,  current structure, and the code you've attempted. Then we can take a look at your use case.

Comment: @Jay Thanks! `/Users/UID` was a link to the document of user who created the post (profiles are stored in *Users* collection). Got it about uid as child.

Answer (score -1):

My approach to this would be to create a new node, used for users personal posts, using their id as key, it will store all posts they have created along with only the id of that post. From there you can determine if the post belongs to the user.

I would also change your security settings to ensure data isn't edited.

Answer (score -2):

You should create a fan-out approach when storing your data.

Create a new sub-tree that will store users posts id

```
   -userPosts
      -userId
         -[postId]
```

This allows you to have a seperate list for each user.  Instead of keeping track of the post object, you simply keep a list of each ID.

To get all posts for a specific user you simply just search this new list of objects.  Find the current users list, then for each postId in the list, make another request to get the corresponding post for that id.

You now have a list of all posts by a specific user :)